# toggleClass on button dynamically Jquery

Tags: jquery

I want to be able to toggle Class in jquery uniquely to multiple button. What currently 
happens is when I click the "viewmore" button they both change at the same time. I want them 
to work independently when clicked.

```js
const $contentId = $('.fad-physician-profile-card-feinstein__column-wrapper').attr("id");
const $contentBody = $('.fad-physician-profile-card-feinstein__column-wrapper').find(".body-section__main")
const $contentBodyArrow = $('.fad-physician-profile-card-feinstein__column-wrapper').find(".icon.icon--angle-thin")
const $contentBodyBtn = $(".fad-physician-profile-card-feinstein__column-wrapper .fad-btn__toggle")

if ($contentBody.length >= 0) {
  $contentBodyBtn.on('click', (e) => {
    $contentBodyBtn.toggleClass("btn-active");
    if ($contentBodyBtn.hasClass("btn-active")) {
      $contentBody.addClass("active")
      $contentBodyArrow.addClass("caret-up")
      $contentBodyBtn.text("View less")
    } else {
      $contentBody.removeClass("active")
      $contentBodyArrow.removeClass("caret-up")
      $contentBodyBtn.text("View more")
    }
  })
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="fad-physician-profile-card-feinstein">
  <section class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-9">
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-sm-12">
            <div class="fad-physician-profile-card-feinstein__profile-image">
              <div class="profile-image">
                <div class="profile-image__initials" data-initials="MD"></div>
              </div>
              <!-- Do not remove needed for font awesome compilation -->
              <!-- class="fal fa-spinner" -->
            </div>
            <h3 class="fad-physician-profile-card-feinstein__title typog-tertiary">King Solomon, </h3>
            <div class="fad-physician-profile-card-feinstein__year">
              <span>1986</span>
            </div>

            <div class="body-section__main" style="">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute
              irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur
              adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate
              velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor
              incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat
              nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna
              aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat
              cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</div>
            <button class="fad-btn__toggle" role="button" aria-label="View more" aria-expanded="false" style="
    top: 11px;
    z-index: 999;
">View more</button>
            <i class="icon icon--angle-thin"></i>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-9">
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-sm-12">
            <div class="fad-physician-profile-card-feinstein__profile-image">
              <div class="profile-image">
                <div class="profile-image__initials" data-initials="MD"></div>
              </div>
              <!-- Do not remove needed for font awesome compilation -->
              <!-- class="fal fa-spinner" -->
            </div>
            <h3 class="fad-physician-profile-card-feinstein__title typog-tertiary">King Solomon, </h3>
            <div class="fad-physician-profile-card-feinstein__year">
              <span>1986</span>
            </div>

            <div class="fad-physician-profile-card__award">
              <a href="https://molmed.biomedcentral.com/articles/10.2119/molmed.2016.00189" target="_blank">A Journey in Science: Cell-Cycle Control</a>
            </div>

            <div class="body-section__main">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute
              irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur
              adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate
              velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor
              incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat
              nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna
              aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat
              cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</div>
            <button class="fad-btn__toggle" role="button" aria-label="View more" aria-expanded="false">View more</button>
            <i class="icon icon--angle-thin"></i>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
</div>
```

Comment: It seems your code example lacks Bootstrap CSS (which I added), and your own CSS is also missing. Please also add [tag:twitter-bootstrap] and the tag matching the version of Bootstrap you are using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this, you don't need to store element in a variable.
If we have to perform same task on multiple button having same class then we can use **$(this)**. When we click any item then that element we can access using $(this), after that using **traversing methods of jQuery** **like(next(), prev(), parent() etc..)** we can traverse in a Dom. I hope it will help you
https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_traversing.asp 
**Your solution:** https://jsfiddle.net/pfsq8oh6/

```
 $('.fad-btn__toggle').click(function(){
    if($(this).hasClass("btn-active")){
      $(this).removeClass("btn-active");
      $(this).text("View more");
      $(this).next('.icon.icon--angle-thin').removeClass("caret-up");
    }else{
      $(this).addClass("btn-active");
      $(this).next('.icon.icon--angle-thin').addClass("caret-up")
     $(this).text("View less");
    }
  });
```

Comment: harsh_apache. that works. My question is how do I apply that same concept of traversing  and adding a class to  "body-section__main" to work dynamically.

Comment: example:  $('.fad-btn__toggle').click(function(){
                   if($(this).hasClass("btn-active")){
                      $(".body-section__main").removeClass("active")
                   }else{
                      $(".body-section__main").addClass("active")
                   }
               });

Comment: ".body-section__main" just comes before that button where we are clicking, so in this case you can use prev(".body-section__main") method of jquery.
Check this updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ovud4qxj/